Type Based on a Generic
I'm wondering, is it possible to access a generic type for unrelated type declarations?
For example, I just wrote this beast just to access the T of a React.Context<T>:
import { nominalTypeHack } from 'prop-types'
import { SomeContext } from '@somelib/someContext';

type SomeContextType = NonNullable<NonNullable<NonNullable<typeof MyContext.Provider.propTypes>['value']>[typeof nominalTypeHack]>['type']

I know I could just declare T explicitely and use it when creating the context and refer to it at all other places, but maybe there's a more dynamic way to achieve that, besides drilling to to the place where the generic is eventually used in a property declaration? So, is there something like
type SomeContextType = GenericTypes(typeof SomeContext)[0]

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but the search results are crowded with questions about how to access a generic type at runtime, which is not what I'm aiming at.

I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for. Can you give usage examples or something like that?

@T.J.Crowder Well, I figure I did a poor job at explaining. I've added an example of what I'm looking for in my question: type SomeContextType = GenericTypes(typeof SomeContext)[0] - is there something like a GenericTypes helper in TypeScript, or a fast-forward way to write something like that on my own?

@DanielA.White I figure it does. If I understand correctly, it's not possible in a generic way, but for each type of interest, e.g. Context in my example. Seems like there's a long-living issue for that: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213
